# Consume Active 911 API

Tags: javascript, c#, php

Is there any sample example or tutorial available that will explain how to consume a Active 911 API?

These are the steps that need to be followed:

1. Get Authorization code
2. Get valid access token
3. Make request to Active 911 API

I am stuck at step 1 as I'm not getting the authorization code. When I make a GET request to

https://access.active911.com/interface/open_api/authorize_agency.php

it redirects me to the member access page.

Is this the normal flow? Am I missing Something? Can anybody guide me on how to consume a Active 911 API?

This is the link that I followed:

http://wiki.active911.com/wiki/index.php/Application_OAuth_Token_Generation

Comment: This is a standard OAuth Authorization Code flow. [This describes it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code). Perhaps you should show us the redirect you're using with your clientid/secret values redacted?

Comment: ok.This is my redirect URI http://localhost/ .So you are saying me being redirected to member access page is the normal flow.Is there any way I can prevent it from being redirected to Member access page?I'm new to this , so please excuse me if it sounds immature.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "member access page" you mean a [consent screen](https://developers.google.com/accounts/images/OAuth2Consent.png) (similar to Google's in the link)? Yes. That's normal for the authorization code flow. --- App redirects to authorize URL and prompts login/consent, after consent is granted it redirects to the URL you specify with the code, you make an API call (back channel) to the provider with your client id and client secret and exchange the authorization code for an access token/refresh token (if you ask for offline access, typically)

Comment: Thank you.This clears my doubt.A bit curious..Is it possible to bypass the member access screen and pass the credentials in the authorization url?

Comment: It depends on Active911, I'm afraid.

Comment: ok .Thanks @john for your support.